# Why is the OpenCL Kernel not using normal x y cooordinates with Image2D?

Tags: c++, image-processing, docker, opencl, gpgpu

### TLDR;

For anyone arriving here whilst trying to figure out how to do gaussian blur or grayscale with OpenCL, the final working code is [here](https://github.com/brett--anderson/opencl-docker). Note that in that repo I'm actually running the whole thing inside Docker with GPU access using Nvidia's Docker wrapper. You can look inside the 'Dockerfile' for the steps that need to be taken to get the code running, or just run it using Nvidia-Docker if you have that setup and are running on an Nvidia GPU.

### Original Question:

Using the following kernel in an OpenCL image filter application I get the expected result, that is, a returned grayscale version of the input image:

```
const sampler_t sampler =   CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE |
                            CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
                            CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

__kernel void process(__read_only  image2d_t src,
                        __write_only image2d_t dst)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    float4 color;

    color = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x, y));
    float gray = (color.x + color.y + color.z) / 3;
    write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(gray, gray, gray, 0));
}
```

So far, so good. I then tried to create a kernel that would just copy across the top and left border of the image:

```
const sampler_t sampler =   CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE |
                            CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
                            CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

__kernel void process(__read_only  image2d_t src,
                        __write_only image2d_t dst)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    float4 color;

    if (x < 10 || y < 10) 
    {
        color = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x, y));
        write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(color.x, color.y, color.z, 0));
    } 
    else 
    {
        write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(0,0,0,0));
    }
}
```

The returned image is not what I expected:
[image: Image that appears incorrectly processed]

I'm loading the input image this way:

```
//  Load an image using the OpenCV library and create an OpenCL
//  image out of it
cl::Image2D LoadImage(cl::Context context, char *fileName, int &width, int &height)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::Mat imageRGBA;

    width = image.rows;
    height = image.cols;

    cv::cvtColor(image, imageRGBA, CV_RGB2RGBA);

    char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(imageRGBA.data);

    cl::Image2D clImage(context,
                            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                            cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8),
                            width,
                            height,
                            0,
                            buffer);
    return clImage;
}
```

The output image:

```
cl::Image2D imageOutput(context,
            CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
            cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8),
            width,
            height,
            0,
            NULL);
```

The Kernel:

```
cl::Program program(context, util::loadProgram("border.cl"), true); 
cl::make_kernel<cl::Image2D, cl::Image2D> filter(program, "process");
cl::NDRange global(width, height);
filter(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, global), clImageInput, imageOutput);
```

Then reading the image back:

```
cl::size_t<3> origin;
origin[0] = 0; origin[1] = 0, origin[2] = 0;
cl::size_t<3> region;
region[0] = width; region[1] = height; region[2] = 1;
float* oup = new float[width * height];

queue.enqueueReadImage(imageOutput, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, oup);

cv::imwrite(filename_out, cv::Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4, oup));
```

Why is the image being processed the way it is? Only selecting pixels with a y coordinate less than 10 seems to work, but selecting pixels with an x coordinate less than 10 seems to stagger across the image.

if I write a test image using the following line in the kernel:

```
write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x,y), (float4)((float)x / 512.0f, 0, 0, 0));
```

I get the following image:

[image: Red channel test gradient]

The first strange thing is that the blue channel is being set, not the red. I have no idea why as I am alway loading and saving the image in RGBA order. Secondly, the banding is very unusual, I'm not sure how to interpret this.

If I use the following line in the kernel:

```
write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(0, (float)y / 512.0f, 0, 0));
```

I get the following image:

[image]

This looks the way I would expect.

I can provide more code if necessary but using the grayscale kernel in the exact same harness works perfectly. As does another kernel not listed here which simply copies all the pixels across.

I'm running the code on and Nvidia Geforce 980M with OpenCL 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was the way I was reading height and width was backwards, i.e.

```
width = image.rows;
height = image.cols;
```

Should have been

```
height = image.rows;
width = image.cols;
```

With this corrected, the rest of the code can stay the same, except the last line where I save the image to disk, here the values need to be swapped again, i.e.

```
cv::imwrite(filename_out, cv::Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4, oup));
```

Needs to change to:

```
cv::imwrite(filename_out, cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, oup));
```

I think this ultimately comes down to the matrix approach to an image where the first coordinate is actually the row number, which is the height and the second coordinate is the column number, which is the width.

The diagnostics @Dithermaster mentioned really helped, as did printing out the assumed width and height, which was ultimately incorrect.

It's interesting that by having both of those errors in the code a pixel for pixel copy worked fine, but once you start to perform actions based on the x,y coordinates you get some really funky results.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing anything obvious yet. One strange thing: your image is CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8 but you're reading it out into an array of floats? How are you displaying it from that? Second, I'm not famliar with your kernel launch technique; what is `filter` and is it launching with dimension of 2? Regarding the issue you're seeing, I'd suggest using process of elimination to figure out where the problem lies. For example, (1) if you remove the conditional and copy all pixels, do you get the whole image? (2) Instead of writing black where the conditional is false, what if you write a Red channel gradient based on X position and a Green channel gradient based on Y position. Do you get a double gradient? Based on results, continue to divide the problem until you find the cause. It looks a lot like a row pitch issue, perhaps in the display function?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try a few of your suggestions today! I'm creating the filter kernel with:

cl::Program program(context, util::loadProgram("border.cl"), true);

cl::make_kernel<cl::Image2D, cl::Image2D> filter(program, "process");

If I remove the conditional and copy everything I get the original image. With the conditional if I don't set the pixels outside the region to black I get the same pattern but what was black is now bits of the terminal. When I apply the grayscale kernel, I get a grayscale image (identical to the original in features, but with a grayscale coloring)

Comment: I'm displaying the image with:

cv::imwrite(filename_out,  cv::Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4, oup));

Comment: I've updated the question to include these extra bits of code

Comment: Apparently CL_UNORM_INT8 allows you to read and write the values as floats. Ive tried changing this to CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and using the read_imageui and write_imageui methods in the kernel but I get the same result. I actually get the same result using any combination of those types and read/write methods